# Running Docker and Jekyll together in a same ec2 instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, jekyll, docker, discourse

I have an application called [discourse](http://www.discourse.org/) running in my ec2 instance .  Its using Docker to serve http requests .

Every thing is working fine with discourse . Now I want to host my [jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/) blog in the same server .

I am able to generate a jekyll site and also I am able to serve pages but the problem is in pointing DNS records .

my discourse site works perfectly with out any hurdles but my jekyll site requires port number to load .

I mean, my blog wont load with out port number in the domain name .

like http://domain.com:4000

How can I run both these application servers to run on port 80 or how to serve requests from port 80 as well as 4000 for any requests .

Please note that I am not in a position to use apache mod_proxy to proxy the requests .

Please suggest a feasible solution . To handle this situation .

Below is my environment details : -

OS : - Ubuntu 13.10 
Ruby version : - 2.0.0

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is to run each app on a different port (e.g. 4000 and 5000), then use a reverse proxy running on port 80 to map different virtual hosts to each application.

Here is a fairly detailed example explaining how to do that with Nginx:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/using-nginx-as-reverse-proxy.html

Out of curiosity, why can't you use mod_proxy in that scenario?

Comment: I knew this, But this is not what I was looking for, I am not running plain Nginx, I am running Nginx with in Docker. So I am expecting solution by considering Docker.